# How to change the default icon for .url in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, icons, filetype

How do I change the filetype icon for `.url`?

I have used [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) to change it, but it does not work.  This initially made me think that the program doesn't work on Windows 8, but it does actually work for other filetypes like `.txt`.

It gives an option to export a `.reg` file instead of directly editing the registry, so I know what it is doing is this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created with Default Programs Editor
; http://defaultprogramseditor.com/

; Edit File Type Icon
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\IE.AssocFile.URL\DefaultIcon]
@="D:\\Icons\\Chrome URL.ico,0"
```

Why isn't it working for this filetype?

Comment: In Win7, I'm using this tool: http://defaultprogramseditor.com/ Does it work in WIn8? Have you tried this?

Comment: @magicandre1981: Yes, that's one of the ones I have tried and it doesn't seem to work (the other was NirSoft FileTypesMan.exe, which refuses to run).

Comment: @magicandre1981: I just tried it again with another filetype (.txt) and it did work.  It does not work on .url bookmarks though, which was what I am trying to change.  Therefore, it looks like this program is actually fine and it is some other issue I am facing.  I've edited my question now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icon of .URL files are treated in another way then normal extensions. The icons are bound to the registered protocol handler which is mostly your default browser.

Additionally the system distinguishes between HTTP, HTTPS, FTP and mailto links
(and some other irrelevant)

[image]

---

But you can change them without to change your default browser. I describe my own approach when I changed the icons.

- First you have to know what browser is registered to your HTTP and HTTPS Windows shortcuts
  (.url files)
- Then you could search in your `regedit.exe` where the default icon is stored. In my example I registered a portable browser with [this guide](http://server-support.co/blog/pc/register-any-browser-as-windows7-default/). As you can see in the guide the default icon is stored in the following location

  ```
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ OperaHTML \DefaultIcon]
  @="C:\\tools\\operaPortable\\opera.exe,0"
  ```

  **Note:** The bold part will differ according to your own registered browser
- The second line defines your new icon. The zero/null at the end defines the used icon index
  which is relevant if your chosen .exe or .dll contains more than one icon. First icon will be index=0, second icon=1 and so on.
- Search for this entry and change the default value 
  [image]
  <sup>Unfortunately I can't give you an English screen but it provides the relevant information too</sup>
- You have to do this for all protocols you want to change.

**Important:** Please take a full backup immediately before you change anything in your registry. This way you can revert easily when you messed up something.

Comment: Thanks.  That has worked for me.  I did make another registry change before, so I am not sure if that was required as well, but I doubt it.  I got that information from this webpage, but it is quite old - http://www.virtualplastic.net/html/icn_file.html#urlicon

Answer (score 2):

[@nixda's answer](https://superuser.com/a/533492/8972) really helped me a ton! I've been looking for ages for a way to change .URL icons (and in most cases, upon changing web browser, it'll change into that browser's default app icon).

Personally, I really like the "old" IE-URL icon, with the light-blue logo of IE11 over a simple page; [preview image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5lsK.jpg).

You'll need to change them one by one, browser by browser, if you want to customize the .URL icon in each browser.
[This thread](https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=47683#p327612) contains instructions for IE; see under the "Code" white box:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.AssocFile.URL\DefaultIcon
```

This is the registry entry for the .URL icon for IE.
The icon we want can be obtained by entering the following in the string (I'm on Windows 10, 64-bit):

```
C:\Windows\System32\url.dll,0
```

For Chromium-based Microsoft Edge, Microsoft Edge Beta and Microsoft Edge Dev, and also Firefox, Vivaldi and Brave Beta (the browsers I'm currently using), these are the respective registry entries:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\DefaultIcon
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeBHTML\DefaultIcon
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeDHTML\DefaultIcon
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FirefoxURL-***\DefaultIcon
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VivaldiHTM\DefaultIcon
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BraveBHTML\DefaultIcon
```

All you have to do is just change them as well to that same icon, or any other of your own preference.

I highly recommend the aforementioned [Default Programs Editor](https://defaultprogramseditor.com) app for everything else, as well for a nice sneak peek on the code to extract icon information from DLL files.

- <del>NOTE: Doing this *may* not change existing Internet shortcuts on your system (you can change them one by one, if you wish, by customizing them from their Properties dialog). However, this will apply to all newly-created shortcuts, across all browsers whose `DefaultIcon` registry entries you have edited.</del>
- ANOTHER NOTE: I don't know exactly why, but from time to time, the Edge browsers will revert back to their standard URL icon. I'm not sure why it happens, I assume it could be related to automatic updates. Editing the entries in Regedit again solves this.