# Changing file type icon association for .URL

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, windows-registry, icons

Since I have set Chrome as default browser, the default icon for .URL files has changed to Chrome icon. I'd like to change it to another icon for .URL files (i.e. not the Chrome icon), while keeping Chrome as default browser.

I have tried the [usual way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427(v=vs.85).aspx) in the registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL\
       (Default key) => "InternetShortcut"
```

then I looked:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\DefaultIcon\
       (Default key) => "C:\Windows\System32\url.dll,5"
```

but it's not this icon: the icon used by Windows explorer is Chrome's icon. Why? **Where/how to change this default icon for .URL files?**

---

Background: I use .URL files a lot as shortcuts for web pages, I can move them on desktop, move them in folders like regular files. I know some people will tell: "use browser bookmarks instead", etc. but I really enjoy working with .URL *files* as bookmarks.

Note: [this topic](https://superuser.com/a/533492/221041) didn't work for me.

Comment: May be the main association set to chrome. There is a user preference registry that saves the program priority for that filetype.

Comment: Ok @Biswa, I did not know there was a priority handling in such cases. How to change the icon then?

Comment: @Biswa I don't find ...Windows\Roaming...

Comment: Is the any registry in this path `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.url\UserChoice`?

Comment: @Biswa there is no such key. Only a reference to `InternetShortcut`.

Comment: Have you tried this utility? https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/